# mbsync not fetching/pushing with [Gmail]/Folders

Tags: email, imap

I've switched from offlineimap to mbsync, but I'm having a problem
syncing certain directories from Gmail.  Specifically, all of the
[Gmail]/FolderName directories seem to be ignored by mbsync (when I run
mbsync -l, it doesn't list any of these).

I have a config like this **[edited to show full config]**:

```
Create Slave

# Account details necessary for logging into the remove server:
IMAPAccount GMAIL
Host imap.gmail.com
User user@gmail.com
Pass pass
UseIMAPS yes
# The certificate of the authority that verified the SSL
# certificate of your email provider:
CertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

# The remote repository:
IMAPStore GMAIL-remote
Account GMAIL

# The local repository:
MaildirStore GMAIL-local
Path ~/Maildir/GMAIL/
Inbox ~/Maildir/GMAIL/INBOX
Trash ~/Maildir/GMAIL/[Gmail].Bin

# Channel connecting two repositories, describing the way the two
# are synchronized:
Channel GMAIL
Master :GMAIL-remote:
Slave :GMAIL-local:
Patterns  "[Gmail]/Sent Mail" "[Gmail]/Drafts" "[Gmail]/Bin" "[Gmail]/Spam" INBOX ARCHIVED
Create Slave
Expunge Both
SyncState *
```

Which seems to conform to examples I've seen online.

Has something changed with mbsync or Gmail which causes mbsync to ignore [Gmail]/Folders?

Comment: Please post your entire config, including the Store sections. Remove any sensitive information first.

Comment: It's on my work computer, so I'll post it on Monday when I have access to it again.

Comment: Ok, edited to show entire config (sensitive info removed).

Comment: It seems that `isync` just doesn't work that well with GMail's (unique/buggy) IMAP implementation. You are probably best to replace your patterns line with `Patterns *` and sync everything. That worked for me when I just tested.

Comment: I tried that, and it pulled everything EXCEPT the [Gmail]/subfolders.

Comment: Then you could try @slm's suggestion of using the -git version, or stick with offlineimap (it does seem to handle the vagaries of Gmail better)...

Comment: I'll try the -git version (once I figure out how to compile it (I don't know how to fulfil the BerkelyDB dependency)) - I would stick with offlineimap, but for this problem: http://askubuntu.com/questions/363367/offlineimap-stopped-working-after-13-10-upgrade

Comment: Have you tried putting your passwords in `.netrc`? That's how I hand them to offlineimap.

Comment: No, I haven't tried that. Do you have a link with info on putting passwords in     .netrc?

Comment: Sure http://www.gnu.org/software/inetutils/manual/html_node/The-_002enetrc-File.html

Answer (score 2):

The project is called [isync](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/isync/). According to the [ArchLinux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Isync) there are supposedly problems with mbsync and GMail. There is a message suggesting that you use [isync-git instead](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/isync-git/).

*excerpt*

> isync can be installed from the AUR. Some problems have been reported when using GMail with the 1.0.6 version. In this case, you can try isync-git.

I also found this thread, seems a bit old at 2008, so things might be different. The thread, titled: [Re: Subfolders and Hierarchies](http://www.mail-archive.com/isync-devel@lists.sourceforge.net/msg00220.html). According to the thread, [mbsync] doesn't support GMail and subfolders.

> > I'm very much interested in using mbsync and mswatch.  I currently use a
> >     ~/Maildir that is INBOX and also contains ~/Maildir/.foo.bar style maildirs.
> >     I've read that mbsync has problems with hierarchies and I've read
> >     comments telling me to read the list archives, but so far I can't make
> >     sense of it.  :)  I'm happy to change my usage patterns, I'm just not
> >     sure what to do to get the ~/Maildir/.foo.bar maildirs synced.  Can
> >     anyone help make this clearer
>
> what you want is not supported.
>   you may try specifying each mailbox separately, both on the client and the 
>   server
>   and connect them, one per channel, and then put them into a group.

This thread also looks to touch on the issues you're having with subfolders too, titled: [offlineimap or mbsync?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mu-discuss/AhgmBAcv-ww).

#### Compiling isync

The OP was attempting to install/compile this on an Ubuntu based system. To compile it you'll need to install the Berkley Data Base (BDB 4.2+). You need to install the library headers for this package, and it needs to be a version that is at 4.2 or higher.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libdb5.3++-dev libdb5.3-dev
```

Comment: I've happily used isync with Gmail; I suspect it is a config error, but let's wait for the OP to post their complete file.

Comment: @jasonwryan - yeah I've never used it so I'm only going on research. Can you use it with subfolders too? Also which version are you using? That seemed to be part of the issue.

Comment: I've used it with a pretty generic Gmail setup. I don't use it day-to-day, only as a recovery tool; so maybe two-three times in the last couple of years (it's great for recreating a remote store from a local copy, `offlineimap` can't do that).

Comment: @jasonwryan - yeah that capability caught my eye so I've added to my todo list as something to use. But i use subfolders and the lack of that feature would be a deal breaker so this is now a interesting Q to me, for selfish reasons 8-).

Comment: If I try to compile isync-git, I get an error: "configure: error: Berkley DB >= 4.2 not found", which I'm not sure how to fix.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 13.10; not sure how to install BDB (and/or point isync-git to the right location).

Comment: @slm No, it doesn't

Comment: @BeSlayed - how about `apt-cache search bdb`?

Comment: Yes, it returns lots of entries, including entries for various versions of Berkeley Database Libraries. I've tried installing     libdb6.0, but when I try to compile isync-git, it still complains about not being able to find Berkley DB >= 4.2.

Comment: @BeSlayed - you need to install the devel or libraries version of these packages, since you're attempting to compile using this package as a depedency.

Comment: @slm Ah, that was the trick. I didn't have the -dev version installed. Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm...running the new git-version, if I have CertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt in my .mbsyncrc it complains that "unknown/misplaced keyword 'CertificateFile'". If I don't, it reports that it's connecting to Gmail and opening up the slave, but doesn't get any further (it just indefinitely sits there).

Comment: @BeSlayed - I'd ask on the forum for isync. http://sourceforge.net/p/isync/mailman/isync-devel/?viewmonth=201311